# How to get URL parameters from H2 Connection?

Tags: java, jdbc, h2

I need to get URL parameters from H2 connection.

This is my code:

```
System.out.println("URL 1:" + url);
var connection = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
System.out.println("URL 2:" + connection.getMetaData().getURL());
```

And this is output

```
URL 1:jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test;MODE=PostgreSQL;DATABASE_TO_LOWER=TRUE;DEFAULT_NULL_ORDERING=HIGH;TRACE_LEVEL_FILE=0
URL 2:jdbc:h2:tcp://localhost/test
```

As we see `connection.getMetaData().getURL()` returns no parameters. Besides `getURL()` returns `String`. However, I need to get URL parameters from `Connection`.

Could anyone say how to do it?

Comment: Why do you need to get the JDBC URL parameters from the connection?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now H2 doesn't provide parameters in url returned from `java.sql.DatabaseMetaData.getURL()` method. On the base of this question an [issue](https://github.com/h2database/h2database/issues/3943) was opened. So, it is possible to check current situation there.